# Check if a string A can be created from string B chars (is abbcccd derived from abcd )?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive method that checks if all string `A` unique chars are a subset of string `B`.

Examples:

- String A = "a"

  1. isTrans(A,"a") == true
  2. isTrans(A,"aa") == true
  3. isTrans(A,"aaa") == true
  4. isTrans(A,"aab") == false
- String A = "acd"

  1. isTrans(A,"addbc") == false
  2. isTrans(A,"aacdd") == true
  3. isTrans(A,"acccd") == true
  4. isTrans(A,"aaaccdd") == true

That's my code:

```
public static boolean isTrans(String s,String t)
{
    boolean isT=false;
    if(t.length()>1)
    {
        if(s.substring(0,1).equals(t.substring(0,1))&&(t.substring(0,1)!=t.substring(1,2)))
        {
            return isTrans(s.substring(1,s.length()),t.substring(1,t.length()));
        }
        if((s.substring(0,1)).equals(t.substring(0,1))&&((t.substring(0,1)).equals(t.substring(1,2))))
        {
            return isTrans(s,t.substring(1,t.length()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isT =(s.substring(0,1).equals(t.substring(0,1)))?true:false;
    }
    return isT;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct

```
t.substring(0,1)!=t.substring(1,2)
```

The == and != operators don't work on strings the same way they do on primitive types.
You could replace it with something like

```
!t.substring(0,1).equals(t.substring(1,2))
```

But a better approach would be to check characters directly.

Try the below snippet i modified to replace substring with charAt.

```
public static boolean isTrans(String s, String t) {
    System.out.println(s + " - " + t);
    boolean isT = false;

    if (t.length() > 1) {

        if (s.charAt(0) == t.charAt(0) && (t.charAt(0) != t.charAt(1))) {
            return isTrans(s.substring(1, s.length()), t.substring(1, t.length()));
        }
        if (s.charAt(0) == t.charAt(0) && t.charAt(0) == t.charAt(1)) {
            return isTrans(s, t.substring(1, t.length()));
        }
    } else {
        isT = (s.charAt(0) == t.charAt(0)) ? true : false;
    }

    return isT;
}
```

Comment: thank you! but it's still return me false at the end and not true.

Comment: I've move the else \ isT = (s.charAt(0) == t.charAt(0)) ? true : false; to the end and it work! 10x!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of regular expressions.

Try this:

```
    String s = "a";
    String t1 = "aa";
    String t2 = "aab";

    System.out.println("t1->" + t1.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1+", "$1").equals(s));
    System.out.println("t2->" + t2.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1+", "$1").equals(s));

    s = "acd";
    t1="addc";
    t2 = "aaaccddd";

    System.out.println("t1->" + t1.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1+", "$1").equals(s));
    System.out.println("t2->" + t2.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1+", "$1").equals(s));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you but I need recursive method.